# Remove single line comment but not the string which is enclosed by single quote

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I am creating a sample code, which parses an SQL file where I have SQL and a commented code block like:

```
-- CREATE PROCEDURE
/* 
 Cleaned By : Tej Kiran
 Cleaned On : 05/12/2009 
 -- Procedure [ChambalSchedules] 
*/ 
CREATE procedure [dbo].[ChambalSchedules] 
( 
 @dyid INT = -1, 
 @dy VARCHAR(10) = '', 
 @yr VARCHAR(10) = '', 
 @dt DATETIME = '', 
 @HID INT = 0, 
 @HsID INT = 0, 
 @CID INT = 0, 
 @ScId INT = 0 
) 
AS 
BEGIN 
 DECLARE @BLID BIT 
 DECLARE @BsID BIT 
 DECLARE @BTID BIT 
 DECLARE @BShId BIT 
 SET @BLID = 0 
 SET @BsID = 0 
 SET @BTID = 0 
 SET @BShId = 0 
...
...
...
 SELECT 
 ShID 
 , ShType 
 , ISNULL(list,'---') AS List
 , Dy 
 , ChambalID 
 , CTypeID 
 FROM #testing1
 WHERE 
 Day = @dyid 
 ORDER BY 
 Day 
 ,ShID 
... .
...
END;
```

**I am using Java to parse queries like this. I want to clean the single line comment which starts with `--` and ends with `\n` but don't want to remove things between quotes: `'text -- text '`.**

I have used following regex:

```
qry= qry.replaceAll("(\s--.*)|((m?)^--.*\n)","");
```

It is working fine in http://regexr.com/ but in my Java code it is removing `'---'` too;

```
qry= qry.replaceAll("(?m)(--.*\\n)", "");
```

Please suggest the correct regex.

I have the following cases:

- Case 1: Line starts with `--` and after that it may have any char or special char between  `--` and `\n` (new line char)

  `-- This is my comment line should be removed`
- Case 2: Line starts other code, and there is a comment at the end of the line.

  `Select * from Table; -- GetListFrom table\n`

  - Note: I want to remove `-- GetListFrom table\n`
- Case 3: If line contains `--` between single quotes, do nothing.

  `SELECT  ShID  , ShType  , ISNULL(list,'---') AS list  , Dy  , chambalID  , CTypeID  FROM #testing1 WHERE  Dy = @dyid  ORDER BY  Day  ,ShID`

  - In this case, nothing should be removed.

Please suggest the correct way to do this.

Comment: Please, try the following pattern `(\n|^)\s*--.*[^']($|\n)`. It also includes option spaces before comment symbols. Remove this part if it is not needed.

Comment: But in this case you will have to replace this string with `\n` or space depending on location of the comment line (first line, last line or line in the middle). The regex above will allow you only to remove comments which start from line beginning.

Comment: The correct way is not to use regular expressions. Instead do a full SQL lexical analysis. Consider for example `'a string' -- 'part of comment'`

Comment: @Henry agree. For handling all the cases mentioned in the topic, the whole query should be analyzed.

Comment: a `--` sql comment line when used in JDBC can really be a mess (it comments out your whole query!). I ran into this problem before and, as painful as it sounds, i had to manually edit the query. if you absolutely need to keep the comments though, i suggest u use `/* */` comment

Comment: Your regex is work well with my sample but not work in actual sql file. I will let you know the exact case, and Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: A word for the unwary: `/* */` comments are nested in SQL, so you can  have `/* comment /* inner comment */ more comment*/`

Answer (score 0):

One of the biggest issues with using pure regex to parse something this complicated is efficiency. So I have ditched the idea in favor of a mixed solution.

I assume that most of your lines will not have `--` anywhere in them. A `Scanner` can be used to get each line, and it's simple to see if there's a `--` present:

```
Scanner getLine = new Scanner(qry);
while(getLine.hasNextLine()){
    String line = getLine.nextLine();
    if(line.contains("--")){
        // replacement happens here
    }
}
```

So fast, and also quite readable. Next, we can use a regex:

```
line.replace("^((?:(?:'[^']*')|[^'-])*)--.*", "$1")
```

Now, when the regex matches, it captures the entire line. That's why it's necessary to have the `$1` replacement. The following parts feed `$1`:

- `'[^']*'` Matches anything between quotes
- `[^'-]` Matches characters that aren't `-` or `'`

The rest of the regex captures `--` and the rest of the characters in the line (remember, the regex is only being applied to one line at a time).

There are some things that this method does not take into account. But it's far more robust than other approaches, so these edge cases are less likely to come up:

- It only works with strings that span one line.
- It does not recognize escaped `'` characters in strings.
- It does not like seeing a single dash outside quotes.

If you feel that any of the above issues are relevant to your issue (or you run into another problem), feel free to tell me, and I will see about updating this answer.